# loop through object until element match

Tags: javascript

I am trying to think of a cleaner way to do this, basically loop through an object and if name matches a keyword do soemthing or if no match is found do something else.

```
var obj = {
    0: {
        name: 'test'
    },
    1: {
        name: 'test2'
    },
    2: {
        name: 'test3'
    },
    3: {
        name: 'test4'
    }
};

var len = (Object.keys(obj).length - 1);
var valuetomatch = 'test2';

while (len > -1) {
    if (obj[len].name === valuetomatch) {
        alert('match: ' + obj[len].name);
        break;
    } else if (len === 0) {
        alert('no match found!');
    }
    len -= 1;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/fw4svrck/

Comment: Is there a reason for this to be an object of objects indexed like that, instead of being an array of objects?

Comment: Since your main object has numeric properties, you really should structure it as an array, which will assign the indexes as you have them automatically. Your array would then consist of object elements.

Comment: And if you make it a real array, you can then use `obj.some(...)` instead of `Object.keys(obj).some` like in the answers.

Comment: if you call this more often, you can create a second object, where the objects are mapped by their name. then you can simply check wether the name in in this map.

Comment: thanks for the replies, this is a very simplified version of what Im working on, so the keys are not always numbers, etc

Answer (score 4):

You could use [`Array#some()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some), if you are sure, that only one item is to search.

```js
var obj = { 0: { name: 'test' }, 1: { name: 'test2' }, 2: { name: 'test3' }, 3: { name: 'test4' } },
    valuetomatch = 'test2',
    found = Object.keys(obj).some(function (k) {
        if (obj[k].name === valuetomatch) {
            // do something
            return true;
        }
    });
document.write(found);
```

Comment: @user1533609 I believe its a typo for `obj`

Comment: `find` would be better than `some`, because it will return first match as object and short circuit loop

Comment: @EliseChant short circuit works with `some` as well, `find` requires ES6, which is not tagged.

Answer (score 1):

This is another way of searching desired item in an object.

```js
var obj = {
 0: {
   name: 'test'
  },
  1: {
   name: 'test2'
  },
  2: {
   name: 'test3'
  },
  3: {
   name: 'test4'
  }
};

var len = Object.keys(obj).length;
var valuetomatch = 'test2';
var flag=false;
for(i=0;i<len;i++){
 if(obj[i]["name"]==valuetomatch){
   flag=true;
   alert(valuetomatch+" is found");
  }
}
if(flag===false)
   alert(valuetomatch+" is not found");
```

Comment: You shouldn't subtract 1 from `.length`.

Comment: And you should break out of the loop when you find a match. And use `true/false` instead of `1/0` for the flag.

Comment: @Barmar, thanks for useful suggestions. I have updated the snippet.

Answer (score 0):

### Don't use this, @Nina's solution is much more efficient.

Using the [`Array#forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) method instead of a while loop makes it much simpler:

```
var obj = {
    0: {
        name: 'test'
    },
    1: {
        name: 'test2'
    },
    2: {
        name: 'test3'
    },
    3: {
        name: 'test4'
    }
};

var valuetomatch = 'test2';
var match;
Object.keys(obj).forEach(function(key) {
    if (obj[key].name === valuetomatch) {
        match = true;
    }
});
if (match) {
    alert('match: ' + valuetomatch);
} else {
    alert('no match found!');
}
```

Comment: Return `false` from the function when you find a match, so the loop will stop.

Comment: @Barmar Thanks, didn't know that.

Comment: @Barmar I just read, MDN says `There is no way to stop or break a forEach() loop other than by throwing an exception. If you need such behavior, the forEach() method is the wrong tool, use a plain loop instead`

Comment: Ahh, that's a feature of jQuery's looping functions, I assumed it was also in the standard functions.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `for..in` loop for iterating through an object

```js
var obj = { 0: { name: 'test' }, 1: { name: 'test2' }, 2: { name: 'test3' }, 3: { name: 'test4' } };

var valuetomatch = 'test2';

var matched = false;

for(var v in obj) {
    if(obj.hasOwnProperty(v) && obj[v].name == valuetomatch) {
        alert('match: ' + obj[v].name);
        matched = true;
        break;
    }
}

if (!matched) {
    alert('no match found!');
}
```

Comment: You should include a `hasOwnProperty` check to prevent errors

Answer (score 0):

for/in loop is an efficient way to go here.

I've re-factored isvforall for/in solution above into a function that you can re-use for other nested objects with similar structure.  toMatch(obj, prop, value) takes 3 parameters: obj (the object you're traversing through), prop (the property you're filtering), and value (the value you're searching a match for).  Can be re-factored further based on data structure.

```
var obj1 = {
    0: {
        name: 'test'
    },
    1: {
        name: 'test2'
    },
    2: {
        name: 'test3'
    },
    3: {
        name: 'test4'
    }
};


var toMatch = function(obj, prop, value) {
  var foundMatch = false;
  for (var key in obj) {
    if (obj.hasOwnProperty(key) && obj[key][prop] === value) {
      alert('Found match! ' + value + ' is found at key ' + key);
      foundMatch = true;
      break;
    }
  }
  if (!foundMatch) {
    alert('no match found!');
  }
};

toMatch(obj1, 'name', 'test2');
// => Found match! test2 is found at key 1
```